# Preparing a manuscript for double-blind review, what is meant by "complete manuscript text minus the title page" and "separate title page"?

Tags: peer-review, anonymity

I want to submit an article to a journal which uses the system of double peer review, the information that I found was the following:

> Confirm that you have prepared: (a) a complete manuscript text minus
>   the title page, acknowledgements, and any running headers of author
>   names so as to permit anonymous review; (b) a separate title page with
>   author information.

so lets suppose that my article has the following structure:

```
Page 1: Title of the article, author, affiliation
Page 2: Abstract
Page 3: Title of the article, Introduction
...
```

so for part (a) what should I include? should I do something like this:

```
Page 2: Abstract
Page 3: Title of the article, Introduction
```

and for part (b) should I submit only:

```
Page 1: Title of the article, author, affiliation
```

is it like that? I have already take care that any reference about me or the place in which I made the research is anonymized. Any help?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer here is to ask an editor since it's your first submission, but I would think that this sounds good. There's a lot more to preparation for double-blind review than taking your names off the front. You've got to do a good job making your self-citations look like references to other people. I.e., instead of saying "in [5] we showed" you say "in [5] Layal, et al. showed", etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  the manuscript (A) should contain the abstract, title and introduction but not the author names and affiliations and should not contain any acknowledgement.

Then, in a separate file (B), you would provide title, author names, affiliations, abstract, introduction and acknowledgements if it applies.